# Changing icon for toggle menu button

Tags: buttons, android, icons

Currently, I have menu button for toggle purpose. User can switch between original web view, or striped down mobile view.

---

### Currently, we are in original web view

[image]

*On action bar, I'm showing a phone icon, which is used to tell user, "By clicking on me, you are going to switch to mobile view"*

---

### Currently, we are in mobile view

[image]

*On action bar, I'm showing a web browser icon, which is used to tell user, "By clicking on me, you are going to switch to original web view"*

---

I was wondering, for a toggle button, should the icon telling

- What will be the next state if user clicks on me?

  - A phone icon indicates if user clicks on me, view will switch to mobile view.
  - A web browser icon indicates if user clicks on me, view will switch to original web view.
- OR, should the icon used to indicate what is current state?

  - A phone icon indicates current state is mobile view.
  - A web browser icon indicates current state is original web view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it this way, then I'd opt for the first option where the icon indicates the *next* state.

However, if possible, I'd actually **show both icons simultaneously** (next to each other) and then use some sort of highlight to indicate the *current* state. The user will then see what the current state is and will intuitively know that clicking on the other icon will change the state to whatever that icon represents.

This provides a better user experience because users can easily see the current state and also see both options at all times.